# Controlling TFT LCD with Arduino

Tags: lcd

I bought [this LCD module](http://www.ebay.com/itm/172272062467?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT). How many pins does this LCD module uses? They have written in the product description that this LCD module uses 8 bit communication, but the LCD module has 16 bit pinout (DB0-DB15). What is the right pin number?

Is there any Arduino LCD library that supports this LCD module, which uses the OTM4001A LCD driver? Usually for LCD the UTFT library works, but it does not support the OTM4001A LCD driver.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Trust what is on the board, not what the eBay seller says. They invariably can't tell the difference between a TFT screen and a doll, and they sell everything in between. They just regurgitate Chinglish nonsense. If the board says DB0-DB15 then DB0-DB15 is what you need to use.

Plus it says in the description:

> Support 16 bit RGB565 format , can connect any 16 bit data bus.

At least this one has told you what the driver chip is (OTM4001A) - many times they can't even do that and don't even understand what you are asking when you request that information.

Mind, it's a driver chip I have never come across before, so maybe I should get one on order to support it in DisplayCore...